# Progress review

Tags: manager

I have been assigned a project and the manager is going to arrange a progress review meeting on a weekly basis. The manager and I do not get along and I will find every chance not to be in the same meeting as her.

I excel in all the projects that I have done so far. She is arranging these meetings so "secretlty" learn how to do the work and frankly I do not want her to learn from me when we are the biggest enemies (it really is that bad).

I cannot say I will not attend the meeting as she out ranks me. How do I cleverly find a way to avoid this?

I was thinking to say - in front of the client - is progress meetings are needed then it should be happening between the manager and the client directly without my presence to discuss any issues IT and myself present. As far as the meetings I need to attend are the ones I arrange directly with the client (this is how I have been doing for sever years) to clarify on the requirements and other matters that comes ad-hoc - for these to happen we dont need too many people and only essential people are needed ie, myself and the client. More people in the meeting more it costs.

What do you think? I really cannot stand her in the same meeting as I am in.

Comment: It sounds like you're essentially saying "I don't want to do my job if I'm working for this manager". There's just no way to do this that doesn't end terribly. Is the relationship with this person so bad you can't even be professional around them?

Comment: "She is arranging these meetings so secretly learn how to do the work" - what actual evidence do you have for this? Do progress reviews with this manager *really* delve that deep into details?

Comment: Do you report to this manager? Or is she a project manager, and you have a seperate line manager?

Answer (score 4):

## Find a new job, then quit.

If the interpersonal strife between you and your boss is so bad that you’d describe her as your “worst enemy”, then there is one obvious solution. Polish off your resume, find another job, then hand in your resignation.

The reason you want to find a new job first is because it’s a lot easier to find a new job in the IT space if you’re currently employed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal process as a manager to want to get an update on a project's timeline. Some manager often talk to the customer to give update. Such paperwork mean to me that she trust you as it seem a big projects and shes is willing to work with you.

Cutting that link will make your project more likely to fail if your manager can't manage your time and feedback correctly, and would possibly bring more animosity in the long term.

To answer you; You could send her a gantt chart update and try to make the meeting the shorter possible, but I would not try to get away from the meeting, but by sending her the necessary information you might remove the necessity of the said meeting.